# jQuery range slider max handle is stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

My question is similar to this one: [jQuery UI Range slider bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987473/jquery-ui-range-slider-bug).  Unfortunately it has not been answered, so I'm asking it too.

I have a range slider where the min and max value can be the same, but the handles cannot pass each other, i.e. if the min handle is moved from 0 to 10, the max handle can be moved from whatever the maximum is down to 10.

When the two handles have the same value, it is possible to move the min handle to reduce the value, but it is not possible to move the max handle at all.  Once the min handle has been moved so that its value has changed, the max handle can be moved again.

Is this a bug in jQuery or is there a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about it being a bug.  Or if there is a concrete solution.  But I did take a crack at the question you referenced and came up with a work around.  It may not help you though if you need the max and min sliders to be able to overlap completely.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987473/jquery-ui-range-slider-bug/19665745#19665745

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Trevor.  I tried it, but no luck.

It seems that, when the handles have the same value, the left handle gets focus and that's it.

Comment: The fix doesn't work in some situations. Please also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36475096/395879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug that is now fixed using the latest jquery-ui files using `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js` it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/c934g/7/